# How do I open google maps app on tapping an address?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-location, android-maps, android-googleapiclient

I have an address param within my app say " 921 Beverly Hills, california, CA- 09001"
Upon tapping this I want google maps to open and show annotation for this exact address. How do I do that?
Any clue?

Answer (score 3):

[launch maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/intents)

There are great resources to get you going this is a sample.  In a real app you would want to handle the intent with your own map activity; maybe add bounds and a camera to zoom in or whatever...

```
Location sf = new Location("");


  sf.setLatitude(37.7749);
  sf.setLongitude(-122.4194);

  requestLocation("your address");



public  void requestLocation(Location location) {



    // Create a Uri from an intent string. Use the result to 
    //   create an Intent.
    Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:" + location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude());

    // Create an Intent from gmmIntentUri. Set the action to 
    //   ACTION_VIEW
    Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
    gmmIntentUri);

    // Make the Intent explicit by setting the Google Maps 
    //   package
    mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");


    if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(mapIntent, REQUEST_LOCATION);
    }
}

public  void requestLocation(String address) {

       // Create a Uri from an intent string. Use the result to create 
      //an Intent.
    Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:" + address);

    // Make the Intent explicit by setting the Google Maps 
    //   package
    mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");


    if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(mapIntent, REQUEST_LOCATION);
    }

}
```

Comment: added a link.  please note that the code does not zoom to the location. I think it puts a tiny gray dot there; no marker...

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find an overview on how to use intents to start Google Maps with an Address:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents

Comment: I didn';t find anything for exact address there. are there any with exact address like mine?

Comment: There was a line of code missing to set the address, sorry.